# Memory Utilization in C# application Compact Framework app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compact-framework

Hello i have developed windows CF c# application which uses SQL connectivity , and Bar-code Scanner , the application runs well sometime , gives Quick response , works fast , but sometimes the application works very slow, it takes more than 1 min to scan barcode. i have checked for other processes working on device but no other running processes found , i am using Wlan Connectivity to fetch data , Data-table in C# app to manage it
please suggest some improvements, changes , or any tasks to improve performance.

Comment: Reading about the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) may help you with your question.

Comment: As a .NET developer you don't need to worry about this :)

Comment: @Fabio, he should actually. And every developer despite  platform and/or programming language should worry about memory. It's a limited resource that can bite you with OutOfMemoryException and sub-optimal performance if you don't treat it accordingly.

Comment: @JurySoldatenkov,  fully agree, sorry it was my try to be ironic. I hope you notice small smile in the comment.

Comment: , pl suggest tricks to improve application Performance(speed) .

Answer (score 2):

CLR maintains graph of special kind, which allows to determinate whether any data is reachable from user main method. If data is not reachable, it is supposed to be unused. It means, that unused data will be deleted. Of course, it doesn't mean that data will be deleted immediately. Garbage collector has some generations of objects, in a nutshell they are collection of objects, sorted by their usage priority. Unused data will be deleted when appropriate generation will be clean up (unfortunately, it is time is not known, it can be happened in any time). You should note, that only unused objects will be deleted from generation and some data can be moved to other generation.